# Is there a way to refresh the channel cache in Discord.Net

Tags: discord, discord.net

I am currently writing a Discord bot.

If it doesn't exist, it is supposed to create a thread in a given channel and write some messages there.

My current way of checking is

```cs
private SocketThreadChannel ThreadIfExists(string id, SocketGuildChannel channel)
        {
            return Context.Guild.ThreadChannels.Where(t => t.ParentChannel == channel)
                          .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Contains(id));
        }
```

where id is a unique id given to each thread.

Most of the time, it works fine; if the thread doesn't exist, the function returns `null,` and I can create the thread myself later, and if it does, it just gets returned to me.

My problem is that if I manually delete one of said threads in discord later, the bot has them saved in cache, and it will still try to write in an unexistent thread.

The only function I could find to refresh the cache is `Context.Client.PurgeChannelCache();`, but it throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, even if I check the client for `null`.

Restarting the bot does fix it, but that's clearly not viable after it gets released.

Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have just made a workaround with a try/catch, where I check if sending the message throws an `Unknown Channel` error and force the creation once again.

I am pretty sure that this is one of the worst ways of doing it, but it does work, I guess